# How to avoid repetitive function call to Ruby hash value?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby

`pkg.A` is called everywhere. I wonder how I can avoid this?
Also, how to simplify the repetitive condition like `pkg.A.B.nil?` and `pkg.A.C.nil?` ?
Thanks!

```
packages = result.packages.collect do |pkg|

{
        :origin => pkg.A.nil? ? nil : {
          :version => ("#{pkg.name}.#{pkg.A.B.version}.#{pkg.A.B.desc}" unless pkg.A.B.nil?),
          :branch => (pkg.A.B.branch unless pkg.A.B.nil?),
          :id => (pkg.A.B.id unless pkg.A.B.nil?),
          :set => (pkg.A.C.set unless pkg.A.C.nil?),
          :event => (pkg.A.C.event unless pkg.A.C.nil?)
        }.compact
}
```

Answer (score 2):

You could use the [safe navigation operator](https://ruby-doc.org/core-2.6/doc/syntax/calling_methods_rdoc.html#label-Safe+navigation+operator) that returns `nil` when called on `nil`.

And for the version identifier I would add a method to `pkg.A.B`.

```
packages = result.packages.collect do |pkg| 
  next unless pkg.A

  { 
    origin: {
      version: pkg.A.B&.version_identifier,
      branch:  pkg.A.B&.branch,
      id:      pkg.A.B&.id,
      set:     pkg.A.C&.set,
      event:   pkg.A.C&.event
    }.compact
  }
 end

# new method on `pkg.A.B`
def version_identifier
  [name, version, desc].join('.') # assuming `name` is available though inheritence or delegation.
end
```

You might also want to consider having a `origin_hash` method on `pkg.A`. Then the whole method could be simplified to:

```
packages = result.packages.collect { |pkg| pkg.A&.origin_hash }
```